# H2 database not able to set default value in a column even though specified in the schema through Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to create a very simple `REST`-based `API` using `H2` DB and `Spring Boot`.

Everything seems to work fine except one part which is the data insertion from `import.sql` file.

The `ACTIVE` column in the table does not get populated with data even though the schema specified the default value as `Y` and `NOT NULL` (See image below).

[image]

**src/main/resources/schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COUNTRY;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY(
    COUNTRY_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    ISO_ALPHA2_CODE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    ISO_ALPHA3_CODE VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    ACTIVE CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL
);
```

**src/main/resources/import.sql**

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Afghanistan','AF','AFG','4');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Aland Islands','AX','ALA','248');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Albania','AL','ALB','8');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Algeria','DZ','DZA','12');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('American Samoa','AS','ASM','16');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Andorra','AD','AND','20');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Angola','AO','AGO','24');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Anguilla','AI','AIA','660');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Antarctica','AQ','ATA','10');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Antigua and Barbuda','AG','ATG','28');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Argentina','AR','ARG','32');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRY_NAME,ISO_ALPHA2_CODE,ISO_ALPHA3_CODE,ISO_NUMERICAL_CODE) VALUES ('Armenia','AM','ARM','51');
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
    application:
        name: country-service

#Datasource settings
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:file:~/test
        username: sa
        password: 
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're somehow using a different schema.

Comment: It's still able to create the table and insert data, except for the one column data that I a talking about. I will be more than happy to fix the schema if you have any pointers.

Comment: The schema you posted and the schema that's being used are not the same. Find out in what other place you create the `COUNTRY` table.

Comment: I found the same issue with h2. It doesn't seem to respect defaults

Answer (score 0):

I beleive Spring boot is doing ddl-auto=createDrop, does the data stay after the application ends? specify `validate` in your application.yml instead. 1 thing that i saw in looking up answers is the default was specified after nullability. the guys in the comments are definitely right about the schema though, if it was really `NOT NULL` h2 would throw error when trying to set column value to null.
ok so it's definitely [Spring boot auto config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)..

`You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are none, validate, update, create, create-drop. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded (default create-drop) or not (default none).`

default is create-drop which creates the schema runs the app then drops it. If you plan to create the schema yourself choose none or validate.

Comment: I am still not clear on this. First thing, the data does NOT stay after the application ends. Second thing, I switched the NOT NULL and DEFAULT 'Y' values and tested it again but no success

Comment: yes it's ddl-auto setting then...  see edit in 2 min

Comment: Nope, this solution did not work. I tried both spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate and re-ran the application. But no success.

Comment: @user2325154 A file named `import.sql` in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is if the `ddl-auto` property is set to `create` or `create-drop`). Should not work for `validate` and `none`

Comment: Does this mean that my import.sql is getting executed at server startup whereby completely ignoring my schema.sql file?

Comment: sry i can try this after dinner and post my findings.